# Tool to count faulty point-curve connections and number of missing connections

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.4

is there any tool in arcgis/arcmap that shows faulty point-curve connection? For example two roads should be at "+" intersection, but they are not? And second- number of missing connections due to undershoots in huge dataset?